# how to update entire column by an array without mulitple update

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array and want to update entire column by its elements.

```
$arr = explode(',', $items);

foreach ($arr as  $el){
    $i = array_search($el, $arr) + 1;
    $sql = "update bplus set uname = '" . $el . "' where id = " . $i;
    $st = $db->query($sql);
}
```

This works, but is there a way to avoid multiple `update` statement?

Comment: Is this with `mysqli`? You could construct a big `$sql` and then run [multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) on it. This might be better for performance. I'm not sure if you can avoid multiple update statements as `el` and `id` change every loop

Comment: Your updating multiple pieces of information so do the multiple updates. Unless you see a noticeable performance issues. Issue with trying an all in one is that usually if one fails they will all get rolled back.

Answer (score -2):

My piece of code for this problem with Prepared statements. It creates a statement for ->prepare() and the parameter-list for ->bind_param().
The ...-operator makes out of array('var1'=>3, 'var2'=> 4) $var1, $var2.

```
    $sql = 'UPDATE bplus SET ';

    foreach($data as $k=>$v) {
        if (gettype($v) == 'string') {
            $params_type .= 's';
        } else {
            $params_type .= 'i';
        }
        $params[] = $v;
        $sql .= $k . '=?,';
    }
    $sql = rtrim($sql, ',');
    $sql .= ' WHERE id=?';
    $params[] = $id;
    $params_type .= 'i';
    $stmt = $this->dbObject->prepare($sql);
    if($stmt === false) {
      echo 'Error: ' . $this->dbObject->errno . ' ' . $this->dbObject->error;
    }
    $stmt->bind_param($params_type, ...$params);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Doesn't solve OP's issue, whilst prepared statements are good for sanitizing user input, the OP wants to reduce the number of `update` calls. And this does not do that.

Comment: Ah, now I get it, I thought he wanted to update different fields in one call. In that case, you're right.

Comment: avoid something does not mean get twice a bulk of some another. Anyway thanks a lot for your effort.